# make popup window movable by picking it from the top

Tags: c, winapi

I am creating a "borderless" window for my game using the win32 api in C using the following window styles:

`WS_POPUP | WS_BORDER | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_THICKFRAME`

When i try to move it around it remains still. Since i added the style `WS_THICKFRAME` i can resize it and i can somewhat "move" it but i would like to know if there is another style/way that makes the window(popup) movable by picking it from the top like normal windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system allows you to customize window behavior based on mouse input. It is sending a [WM_NCHITTEST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-nchittest) message to the window's window procedure, allowing client code respond as desired.

Returning `HTCAPTION` from a `WM_NCHITTEST` message handler requests that the system responds as if the window caption was clicked, thereby allowing it to be moved.

To retain normal functionality, a client would typically forward the `WM_NCHITTEST` message to `DefWindowProc`, and return `HTCAPTION` when default processing returned `HTCLIENT`:

```c
case WM_NCHITTEST:
{
    LRESULT position = DefWindowProc(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
    return position == HTCLIENT ? HTCAPTION : position;
}
```